# Kiosk application update and restart

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a kiosk app on Android 7 or 9, it is device owner with pinned screen. I download new version of the app (.apk) and install it using PackageInstaller in my kiosk app:

```
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(apkfile);

            PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
            params.setAppPackageName(context.getPackageName());
            // set params
            int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
            PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
            OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

            int c;
            while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, c);
            }
            session.fsync(out);
            in.close();
            out.close();
            session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
```

This closes my currently running kiosk app. When I manually run it again I can see it has been updated. However, I don't want my kiosk app to be closed, it must be automatically restarted when the updated apk is installed. How to restart my kiosk app when the update is installed?

I already tried broadcasts MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED, PACKAGE_REMOVED, PACKAGE_ADDED, PACKAGE_REPLACED but my kiosk app never receives them in its BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by Lenovo tablet. You have to enable Apps -> Settings -> Background app Refresh for your app. Otherwise ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED doesn't work. More info: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and/Tab-4-7-Essentials-autostart-disabled/m-p/3840211